# Websphere ScheduledExecutorService Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, websphere, threadpool, scheduledexecutorservice

If I use the following code to asynchronously run a job at scheduled interval in Websphere, it is my understanding that this creates a thread outside of the Websphere JEE context, because this thread is not able to find datasources etc configuered in Websphere.

```
    final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
       public void run() { System.out.println("beep"); }
     };
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 10, 10, SECONDS);
```

My question is if I shutdown websphere, does the thread created for scheduled service dies or does it keep running because it was created outside of the JEE context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you shutdown websphere it basically means you shutdown the process that runs JVM so every thread running in it will be stopped.